# sem_open() error: "undefined reference to sem_open()" on linux (Ubuntu 10.10)

Tags: c++, linux, semaphore

So I am getting the error: "undefined reference to sem_open()" even though I have included the <semaphore.h> header.  The same thing is happening for all my pthread function calls (mutex, pthread_create, etc).  Any thoughts?  I am using the following command to compile:

g++ '/home/robin/Desktop/main.cpp' -o '/home/robin/Desktop/main.out'

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const char *serverControl = "/serverControl";
sem_t* semID;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    //create semaphore used to control servers
    semID = sem_open(serverControl,O_CREAT,O_RDWR,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need link with pthread lib, using `-lpthread` option.

Answer (score 6):

Including the header does not tell ld about the library.  You need to add -lrt to your compilation command line.  For threading, you need either -lpthread or -pthread, depending on your platform.

The library is not the header.  The header is not the library.  This is an important distinction.  See [What's the difference between a header file and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library)

Answer (score 3):

The working option in Ubuntu is **-lpthread**. But if you work on suse or other systems the correct option is **-lrt**. Also the book **Linux Programmin Interface** mentions **-lrt** as the correct option.