# How to use class from app in library loaded by app

Tags: c++, qt, build, linker

I have a qt app that loads qt plugins (libraries) at runtime.  I want to pass a class C to the libraries. To use the class in the library I have to include it. Does this imply that the object file of C is linked in every library built library? If so, how can I avoid linking the object file of the visitor class?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415906/how-does-h-lib-dll-works-together) help to explain things better?

Comment: This is the basic knowledge I have about the linking system. But my question is more about the case, when the parameters passed are neither basic types nor complex types avabilable to both binaries, e.g. those provides by libstd.