# Basic definitions/difference b/w Library and Headers

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, header-files

I'm confused about these two terms: **Library** and **Headers**.

Headers contain function definitions as far as I know, but I don't have any concept of Library. I'm a new programmer and have worked with C language a little. I am now learning C# so keep explanations in simple terms. If possible provide examples also as I've tried this link:

[What's the difference between a header file and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library)

But I am unable to make an exact picture of these terms in mind.

Comment: Well, if that stackoverflow answer isn't clear enough....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the link say, the interface (header) tells you how to call some functionality (without knowing how it works), while the implementation (library) is the actual functionality.

Example:
To use the `printf` function you need to include the header  and the  tells you how to call the printf function. It says, `printf` can be called like this

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

The library is the one which implements it

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... )
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

One more example:
On linux, if you want to work with xml file, there is `libxml` library. Suppose, if you want to read a xml file, there are function exposed like

```
xmlTextReaderRead,  `xmlReaderForFile` etc...
```

These function are declare in the header file `<libxml/xmlreader.h>` means this `<libxml/xmlreader.h>` header tells you how to call the above said function, mean what parameters this function takes and what is its return value.

The library `libxm2` implements these function and you have to link this library when you compile the code.