# First index of a non-Whitespace character in astring in C

Tags: c, strchr

How do I get the index of the first non-whitespace character in a string. 
For example for the string `"   #$%abcd"` I would expect getting the index 3  for `#`.

Comment: For some reason the white space in the string I wrote aren't showing in the question.

Comment: Have a look at the C standard library functions for strings and characters. You will find the relevant functions in there.

Comment: Take a look at `strspn`.

Comment: There's a function called `isspace()` in `ctype.h` that should come in useful.

Comment: @Ryan does this also work for C? I am asking because the page displayed is for C++.

Comment: @71GA: Not sure what you mean by “page displayed”; I didn’t link to anything. `strspn` is a C function in `string.h`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not code it instead of include other libraries:
Here is a starting point:

```
int main () 
{
    char s[] = "   #$%abcd\0";
    size_t i = 0;
    while(s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\t'|| s[i] == '\n' || s[i] == '\r' || s[i] == '\f' || s[i] == '\v')
    {
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

`i` is the index of the first non-whitespace char:

Comment: @Aconcagua, Yes, but then the library `#include <ctype.h>` must be included making it implementation specific, one small advantage of the implementation is the OR switch, I set the chars in  order (IMHO) of probability of occurence in a "normal" text from left to rigth.

Comment: @GurstTavo Curious you consider `s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\t'|| ...` an advantage over `isspace()`.  `isspace()` is routinely a lookup  into a table - no need for ordering in probability of occurrence.

Comment: `isspace()` is part of the standard library, so using it doesn't make the code all that implementation specific.  And ctype.h is just a header not a library... you're most likely already linking to the library it goes with, and won't really add much extra code to the executable by using a function from it.

Comment: @chux, Yes, you are rigth, but still not sure if two dereferences (in the implementation I'm looking at) are better or worse than the 6 (worst case) comparisons OR switched. Maybe a runnig a profile tool may help, just for couriosity.

Comment: @Dmitri, Thanks I checked and `isspace()` is declared in `ctype.h`, but after a short test the code compiles w/o any header including the `isspace()` function call. Also I'm confused about the definition of **library**. Yes `ctype.h` is a header, but also `stdlib.h` is a header. both implement functionality and macros.

Comment: Header files usually *don't* implement functionality (aside from macros and inline functions, sometimes)... they merely provide declarations for functions and objects implemented elsewhere. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library

Answer (score 2):

Use `strspn()` to find the length of the whitespace and then skip past it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

const char whitespace[] = " \f\n\r\t\v";
char *str = "    Hello World!";

void main() {
    char *stripped = str + strspn(str, whitespace);
    printf("Stripped msg: '%s'", stripped);
}
```

Comment: What is `<strings.h>`?

Comment: OT: `main()`  returns `int` not `void`.

Comment: <string.h> and <strings.h> are equivilant. I beleive that POSIX says that either can be used.

Comment: how do you know the OP is using POSIX? and if they're equivalent, what's the point of include both anyway?

Comment: Just habit, nothing more. Anyway, it's more likely to compile on an unknown machine.

Comment: It probably compiles on few machines,  namely only on those providing *both* of your string headers.

Answer (score 0):

Old school:

```
const char *ptr;
for (ptr=str; *ptr && ((unsigned char)*ptr) <= ' '; ++ptr);
return (*ptr ? ptr-str : -1);
```

Comment: This does make some assumptions about the character set... but it should work for ASCII, provided all control characters are to be treated as whitespace.  `isspace((unsigned char)*ptr)` may be better than `((unsigned char)*ptr) <= ' '`.

Comment: isspace is locale-sensitive.  OK if that's what you want...  If it's not, then what characters do you really want to skip?  <=' ' is fast and skips an acceptable char set for must uses.