# How to link my static library to my c++ project CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm using CLion with CMake. I have my own static library "libxxx.a".
I'm trying to link it this way in CMakeLists.txt:
`target_link_libraries(myProject ./lib/libxxx.a)`
And this way I'm including library to my main.cpp.
`#include "xxx.h"`.
But I have error `fatal error: xxx.h: No such file or directory`.
What should I do?

Comment: What did you set in your `include_directories` list?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if the library is built as part of your project, don't use the library name but the *target* name instead.

Comment: I'm not using `include_directories`

Comment: That is your problem. Unless they are in system header paths you will need to add include_directories() for the headers for your library.

Comment: @KyryloOnufriiev Have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library It may help you understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

### CMake include a prebuilt static library

As a sketch you need your project to look something like this

```
project( myProject )

set( SOURCE_FILES main.cpp )

add_library( myLibrary STATIC IMPORTED )
set_property( TARGET myLibrary PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /path/to/lib/libxxx.a )
include_directories( /path/to/headers/ )

add_executable( myProject ${SOURCE_FILES} )
target_link_libraries( myProject myLibrary )
```

You might be able to replace `include_directories` with:

```
set_property( TARGET myLibrary PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /path/to/headers/ )
```

A better way to go is to compile the static library from source and then use

```
target_include_directories( myLibrary PUBLIC /path/to/headers/ )
```

And then they get handled automatically.

Comment: + for spaces after parenthesis