# Linux Kernel Libraries

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Is there an **API/way** to know what **Linux Kernel** headers replace what user space headers for instance: `linux/string.h` instead of `string.h`?
 All I found was this website:[The Linux Kernal API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/index.html) but it didn't say what headers to include in my code in order to use the functions listed.

Comment: `string.h` is  called a "header file". It definitely is not a library. You might like to [read here on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while no API found, a good way for me is to use :

[Documentation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source)

and the following guide:

[Kernel Guide](https://linux.die.net/lkmpg/index.html)