# What is the equivalent of GEMS of RUBY in C++?

Tags: c++, ruby

I feel that header files which  i include in c++ acts as equivalents of GEMS in ruby but i am not sure.A brief description of gems along the lines of c++ will be helpful

Comment: Packages, libraries.

Comment: I suggest to check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library)

Answer (score 2):

In languages such as Ruby and Java you merely 'require' or similar a package (which is called a gem in Ruby). In C++, you generally need both to #include one or more header files, and also to link with a (dynamic or static) library.