# In a C program, what exactly happens under the hood if I call a function from a header file from /usr/include?

Tags: c, linux, standard-library, c-standard-library

The header files of C library functions can be found under /usr/include. The actual source files, however, don't seem to be simply located anywhere in the file system.

So what exactly happens under the hood if I call a function from a header file from /usr/include in my C program?

Comment: We'll need some focus here.

Comment: The source code has been precompiled into a *library* which is linked to your program.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library

Comment: Have you looked at what's in `/usr/lib`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a header file and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library)

Comment: Look at the community wiki answer at the proposed duplicate. The accepted answer is not close enough to your question.

Comment: @Yunnosch: The link is helpful but it doesn't give tangible examples of libraries. What's the name of the C standard library file? (If it matters, I run the current version of Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of the C library is typically stored on the system as a *shared library* which typically has a .so extension.  These libraries typically live in /usr/lib, although they can reside in other locations based on the system.

When your program is compiled and linked, it is automatically linked to the C standard library.  Then when it runs, it loads the shared libraries that are linked with it.

Comment: Thanks! What's the name of the shared library file for the c standard library? If it changes over time, I run the current version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @cssdev It's likely `glibc.so` on your Ubuntu system. Look in `/usr/lib` for shared objects with `libc` in the name. The standard one is generally a symbolic link to a specific version.

Comment: The "run time c library" is `libc.so.6` .

Comment: @h0r53: I don't have "glibc.co". The only file matching "libc*" in /usr/lib/directly is "libcue.so.1 -> libcue.so.1.0.4". Is it this?

Comment: @KnudLarsen: I don't have a file ending in ".6" but I have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so which seems similar enough. So that's it probably.

Comment: @cssdev yes that's it. It could very well be a symbolic link as well.

Comment: Debian based OS's like Ubuntu : `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libc6/filelist ...... Else `/lib64/libc.so.6`

Comment: Thanks! I only looked in /usr/lib, not in /lib. Now I've found it.