# Why Can't the Linker Find SDL2 When the XCode Editor Can? (C, Apple Silicon)

Tags: c, macos, linker-errors, sdl-2, apple-silicon

So, I've been trying to use SDL2 with C for a while, and I've checked many other forum posts that don't help.

When editing the c file, the XCode editor finds `SDL2/SDL.h` fine, but when I go to run it, it fails with exit code 1:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D?-erkhscnzezhtcwacawddllxsmicc/Build/Products/Debug/3D? normal (in target '3D?' from project '3D?')
    cd /Users/<username>/Desktop/3D\?
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Xlinker -reproducible -target arm64-apple-macos14.2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.2.sdk -O0 -L/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D\?-erkhscnzezhtcwacawddllxsmicc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug -L/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D\?-erkhscnzezhtcwacawddllxsmicc/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D\?-erkhscnzezhtcwacawddllxsmicc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug -F/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D\?-erkhscnzezhtcwacawddllxsmicc/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D\?-erkhscnzezhtcwacawddllxsmicc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/3D\?.build/Debug/3D\?.build/Objects-normal/arm64/3D\?.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/homebrew/include/ -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D\?-erkhscnzezhtcwacawddllxsmicc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/3D\?.build/Debug/3D\?.build/Objects-normal/arm64/3D\?_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D\?-erkhscnzezhtcwacawddllxsmicc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/3D\?.build/Debug/3D\?.build/Objects-normal/arm64/3D\?_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D\?-erkhscnzezhtcwacawddllxsmicc/Build/Products/Debug/3D\?

ld: Undefined symbols:
  _SDL_CreateRenderer, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_CreateTexture, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_CreateWindow, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_DestroyRenderer, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_DestroyTexture, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_DestroyWindow, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_GetError, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_GetKeyboardState, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_Init, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_PollEvent, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_RenderCopyEx, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_RenderPresent, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  _SDL_UpdateTexture, referenced from:
      _main in main.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

(Note: what is above is the invocation)

Everything it is erroring on is due to the linker not finding `SDL.h`.

I have tried using terminal to compile, and have used both `clang` and `gcc`, both gave the same result. I tried appending `-lsdl2`, but that didn't work.

I have also tried adding the SDL2 header files to my project and accessing it locally, but none of the following worked:

`#include <SDL2/SDL>` <- finds this in editor

`#include "SDL2/SDL"` <- finds this in editor

`#include "./SDL2/SDL.h"` <- finds this in editor

`#include "../../../../opt/homebrew/include/SDL2/SDL.h"` <- finds this in editor

Although the editor finds the header files and lets me use them, whenever I try to run, it fails.

I have successfully compiled, assembled, and analyzed my file without errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The linker doesn't care about header files. It links together object files and libraries to create the executable. You need to add the path to the libraries in the linker options or on the command line depending on how you are compiling, and you need to tell it which libraries to link.

Comment: https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/mac/xcode/index.php may be helpful. https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/issues-using-sdl2-on-xcode-on-macos/37776 too.

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding seen with beginners. A header ist not a library. A header only tells the compiler what is available somewhere else. The library then brings the implementation. Your editor does not find the library but only the header.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a header file and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library)

Comment: @RetiredNinja, thank you! That's good to know. I downloaded the tarball and not the disk image when I first tried that.